# Can the sum of 2 polynomial subspaces be bigger than the original space?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I have been having some trouble with getting my head around this problem,

let $K[x]_{\leq4}$ be the vector space of polynomials with grade less than or equal to 4
and let $V_p$ be the subspace of all those polynomials with a root in $-2,2,0$ and $V_d$ the subspace that have a root in $-1,1$. Calculate basis and dimensions for $V_p,V_d,V_d \cap V_p,V_p+V_d$

and so far I calculated the basis like this:
$V_p$ can be factored into $V_p(x)=x(x-2)(x+2)(ax+b)$ and $V_d$ like this $V_d(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(ax^2+bx+c)$
so i decided to use the basis $<{x(x-2)(x+2),x^2(x-2)(x+2)}>$ for $V_p$ and $<(x-1)(x+1),x(x-1)(x+1),x^2(x-1)(x+1)>$

So of course I concluded that their dimensions are $3$ and $2$

However where I am having some trouble is calculating $V_d \cap V_p,V_p+V_d$
because for example for $V_d \cap V_p$ I believe that it is meant for a vector space of polynomials less than grade 4 whose roots are $0,1,-1,-2,2$ nut that would imply that the polynomial has to at be grade at least $5$ right? and wouldn't that leave me with the solution to be the set only containing the 0 polynomial?

And then that gives me more trouble to calculate $V_p+V_d$.

I've been in this problem for a while and still can't see where I'm wrong
I hope I have been clear enough, and thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I don't understand your question, because $V_p$ is not a subspace. For instance, $x,x-2\in V_p$, but $x+(x-2)\notin V_p$. Perhaps that you meant that $V_p$ consists of those polynomials such that each of the numbers $-2$, $0$, and $2$ is a root.

Comment: From what I see on the problem it is said that these two are indeed subspaces, it was asked of us to prove it

Comment: Well, if $V_p$ that way, I proved that it is *not* a subspace. Do you see some error in my proof?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: the way I read the problem $V_p$ contains of polynomials which have three roots i.e, at -2, 2 and 0, but in you example the polynomials have one root each, i.e. neither $x$ nor $x-2$ are in $V_p$.

Comment: Wouldn't $x$ not belong to $V_p$ because at $x=2$ it does not equal $0$?

Comment: What you wrote is that $V_p$ consists of those polynomials with **a** root in $\{-2,0,2\}$. Clearly, $x$ has a root in that set (that root is $0$). Don't you agree?

Comment: @Ramirogenta: I agree with you that $V_p \cap V_d$ is empty. This would also mean that $V_p + V_d = K[x]_{\leq 4}$

Comment: @blamocur I wrote in my first comment that if we define $V_p$ as the set of all polynomials $P(x)$ such that $-2$, $0$, and $2$ are roots of $P(x)$, then $V_p$ is indeed a subspace. But that's not what is written in the body of the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oh yes I can now see what you mean, I was reading it differently, yes indeed x has a root in 0, so just to be certain, it would only be a subspace if $V_p$ would be the set of polynomials in which it has 3 roots $0,2,-2$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.